# Sort array of array on string value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, lodash

I want to sort the array of array on length of string, as follows

```
var arr = [
   [1951, "Mayfer"],
   [1785, "Actinac Capsules"],
   [1007, "Ferri Injection"],
   [1101, "Cetaphil"]
];

var sortedArr = sortOnLengthOfString(arr);

>> sortedArr = [
  [1951, "Mayfer"],
  [1101, "Cetaphil"],
  [1007, "Ferri Injection"],
  [1785, "Actinac Capsules"]
]
```

Is there a solution with lodash preferably? Or plain Javascript?

I haven't found duplicate question yet. Can someone find it? Please note, the sorting I am asking for, is for array of arrays and not array of objects.

Comment: there is no object anywhere. all of these are arrays.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*...? `obj.sort((a, b) => a[1].length - b[1].length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) at this context,

```
var obj = [
   [1951, "Mayfer"],
   [1785, "Actinac Capsules"],
   [1007, "Ferri Injection"],
   [1101, "Cetaphil"]
];

obj.sort(function(a,b){ 
    return a[1].length - b[1].length 
});

console.log(obj);
//[[1951, "Mayfer"],[1101, "Cetaphil"],[1007, "Ferri Injection"],[1785, "Actinac Capsules"]]
```